# Why jQuery validation doesn't work reliably?

Tags: jquery, validation

Sometimes the unobtrusive validation appears, sometimes not.

Unobtrusive validations works reliably only when I explicitly call form's valid() function (done during submit)

Why is this so?

The code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form action="/User/Input" id="fxUser634377199694370000" method="post">    
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
      <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Firstname field is required." id="Firstname" name="Firstname" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Firstname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      <label for="Lastneim">Lastneim</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Lastneim field is required." id="Lastneim" name="Lastneim" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Lastneim" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      <label for="Age">Age</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Age must be a number." data-val-required="The Age field is required." id="Age" name="Age" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Age" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id='fxUser634377199694370000_Saver' value="Save" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#fxUser634377199694370000_Saver').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($('#fxUser634377199694370000').valid())
        ;
      else {
        alert('not ok');
        return;
      }
      alert($('#fxUser634377199694370000').serialize());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Functional code, sans server code, only html and client-side(jquery libraries): http://www.sendspace.com/file/913i1w

Comment: well, seems to work for me, except for ckeditor (always have to click twice)

Comment: Your going to have to give us more than that.  Some code and a description of a way to reproduce.

Comment: The way the system works is like this. Validation takes place in 2 cases. 1. onSubmit => everything gets re-validated!. 2. onBlur on a field with an active error message => that field gets revalidated. Are you getting different results ?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this behavior. It still exists in jquery.validate 1.9.0 with jquery 1.8.3. There seems to have been a fix proposed then reverted due to introducing another bug. https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/524

RARPSL's comment suggested a fix but I cannot understand how to implement what he described. Can you?

Answer (score 5):

The [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) say: "Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages - he won't get bugged before he had the chance to actually enter a correct value".

Is that what bugs you?

Comment: I tried entering text on textboxes and tried to delete the entered value, I suppose the unobtrusive validation will already kick-in even I don't click the submit button

Comment: That's the intended behaviour. The user can edit the form until it's like she meant, then she clicks 'submit' and the input gets validated. From that moment the input fields are eagerly validated. As soon as the content of a field is valid, the error message disappears, and when then content is edited invalidly, it appears  again.

Comment: Try entering values on Firstname and Lastname, then tab to Age, then tab to Firstname and delete its value, the validation is not kicking in.

Comment: Then relaunch the html, then enter values on Firstname and Lastname textboxes again, then tab to Age. But this time, instead of deleting the Firstname, delete the Lastname, the validation kicks in.  It's this inconsistencies that is unexplainable to users, even to me. What's the difference between deleting the first textbox and second textbox value?

Comment: Enter a value for Firstname, leave out Lastname. Click 'Submit'. The validation should now mark Lastname as missing. Then delete the value for Firstname (maybe leave/blur Firstname, not sure), then validation should mark Firstname as well. That's how it's meant to be according to the docs. Do you experience it differently? (Talking about jquery Plugins/Validation)

Comment: The use case is the user is not yet clicking submit. I'm thinking why the first textbox is discriminated against validation, while the second textbox is eagerly validated even the user is not clicking the submit button yet

Comment: Sans submitting, to make things interesting, the only time the first textbox is validated is when you enter value to it then tab to second textbox then tab back to first textbox and delete the first textbox's value, the first textbox will be validated. Reload html, if you enter value in first textbox, then tab two times(will fall to Age textbox, enter valid number), then tab back to first textbox, then delete its value, the first textbox's validation will not kick-in

Comment: @Hao: I am noticing the same problem in IE8. Have you found a fix for this? I thought I was doing something wrong but it seems to be a bug.

Comment: @havok Not yet. But I'm glad(and sad at the same time) that somebody notices this bug. Other answers are sort of "When ideas fail, words come in very handy." jQuery unobtrusive validation is a nice component, the behavior though is not consistent. Need to file this bug to jQuery team

Comment: @Hao It is nice, so i'm putting up with the problem. Hopefully our users dont' notice. I have filed a bug on their github so hopefully that gets seen soon. I hope you don't mind, but I used your jsfiddle as an example. https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/110

Answer (score 1):

Normally i would be satisfied with lazy validation but on a very specific app this is not the case. Inspired by @Peeter i'm calling validation like:

```
$("#wep_key_register_test_second").focus(function() {
    $("#wep_key_register_test_second").valid();
});
```

and afterwards letting the plugin function normally.

Answer (score 0):

Like the documents say, validation is lazy until the first time valid() is called.

### A workaround for this is to call the valid() method yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/e6et6/

Comment: I already stated that on my question "Unobtrusive validations works reliably only when I explicitly call form's **valid()** function (done during submit)" I'm just baffled with inconcistencies of validations prior to clicking submit(or calling **valid()**)

Comment: Look at this this way, the form will not have any validation before you actually call the valid() method. After the method is called, validation kicks in.

Comment: Even I look at it that way, the reality tells otherwise. Even when valid() is removed (http://jsfiddle.net/FxCfg/) on jquery's ready, it still has validations, try to input values on Firstname, Lastneim, Age, then try to delete them one by one, I would not be bothered if all of them are not validated, however, the Lastneim is validated; it is that inconsistency that make me scratch my head in disbelief. Though calling valid() on jquery's ready make things consistent, aesthetic-wise it doesn't look good